# CSS: position of div is off after letting go of draging

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

In my ionic application, I've got a `div` with a class "`scroll`". Whenever I click on and hold it, and drag it, I see that an attribute "`transform`" with the value `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1)` is added to the styles of that div.

When I drag it down the y value in `translate3d` increases. When I let the `div` go, the y value transfers back to 0px. When I drag it up, the y value in  `translate3d` decreases. However when I let the `div` go, the y value doesn't transfer back to 0px but to -14px, meaning it is now a little bit higher in comparison to before I drag it.

I now don't understand where this -14px is coming from. I can drag it as high as I want, the value always settles to -14px after letting the div go. I want the div to be in the same position as before and not 14px higher.

I tried to manually set the `transform` attribute to `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1)` in my css file. But dragging the div overwrites that value.

Structure of that view looks something like this:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" can-swipe-back='false'>
  <ion-content class="padding main-content-background">
    <div style="height:100%">
      <div class="foo" style="background:white;height:93%;width:100%;border-radius:5px;overflow:hidden">
        <ion-scroll id="fooID" direction="xy" min-zoom="1.0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <div>
            <div id="anotherID">
              <div class ="fooContainer">
                <div class="row" style="top:2em;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-scroll>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: And what kind of framework do you use for this click and drag functionality? Can you show us some code?

Comment: No framework is responsible for that drag functionality. It's a div (a) within another div (b). I found out div a is bigger than div b. In iOS, if you've got a div within a div, then you can drag that div around as well.

Comment: ... I think it's because the div within is taller than the outer div. The 14px is probably the 'height' difference of the inner div to the outer div.